# How to access struct inside another struct

Tags: c, struct

I have the following struct arrangement, and I'mstruggling to get the data contained within the first `myNestedStruct` part of the data.

```
struct myNestedStruct
{
    char programName[28];          

    union
    {
        float parameters[1];        
        struct
        {
            long size;      
            char info[1];      
        } datas;                 
    } contents;                  

} myNestedStruct;

struct myStruct
{    
    int ID;             
    int numIDs;        

    union
    {        
        myNestedStruct programs[1]; 

        struct        
        {
            int size;                
            char info[1];   

        } datas;                    

    } contents;                         
};
```

Should I be accessing it like this:

```
myStruct.contents.programs[0].contents.datas
```

Comment: `struct myNestedStruct`-> `typedef struct myNestedStruct`

Comment: @MichaelWalz: ...or: `myNestedStruct programs[1];` --> `struct myNestedStruct programs[1];`

Comment: "*`myStruct.contents ...`*": The is not `myStruct` defined by the code you show. There is only `struct myStruct`. Same for `myNestedStruct`.

Answer (score 3):

Your definitions are not consistent.

Either use *named* structs, and only *named* structs:

```
struct MyNestedStruct /* note: no typedef, but a name */
{
  char programName[28];          

  union
  {
    float parameters[1];        
    struct
    {
      long size;      
      char info[1];      
    } datas;                 
  } contents;                  
};

struct MyStruct /* note: no typedef, but a name */
{    
  int ID;             
  int numIDs;        

  union
  {        
    struct MyNestedStruct programs[1]; /* note the struct */

    struct        
    {
      int size;                
      char info[1];   

    } datas;                    
  } contents;                         
};
```

Then define a variable like this:

```
struct MyStruct myStruct;

myStruct.contents.programs[0].contents.datas ...;
```

or use *typedef'ed anonymous* structs, and only *typedef'ed anonymous* structs:

```
typedef struct /* note: typedef, but NO name */
{
  char programName[28];          

  union
  {
    float parameters[1];        
    struct
    {
      long size;      
      char info[1];      
    } datas;                 
  } contents;                  
} MyNestedStruct;

typedef struct /* note: typedef, but NO name */
{    
  int ID;             
  int numIDs;        

  union
  {        
    MyNestedStruct programs[1]; /* NO struct, as typedef'ed above */

    struct        
    {
      int size;                
      char info[1];   

    } datas;                    
  } contents;                         
} MyStruct;
```

Then define a variable like this:

```
MyStruct myStruct;

myStruct.contents.programs[0].contents.datas ...;
```

You *could* mix these two approaches, but doing so just leads to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Structure syntax is

```
struct [structure tag] {

   member definition;
   member definition;
   ...
   member definition;
} [one or more structure variables];
```

Here structure tag is optional.

so changes in your code are

```
struct myNestedStruct
{
    char programName[28];          

    union
    {
        float parameters[1];        
        struct
        {
            long size;      
            char info[1];      
        } datas;                 
    } contents;                  

} ;  //Removed variable

struct myStruct
{    
    int ID;             
    int numIDs;        

    union
    {        
        struct myNestedStruct programs[1]; //Added struct keyword

        struct        
        {
            int size;                
            char info[1];   

        } datas;                    

    } contents;                         
} var;  //Declared variable
```

> How to access struct inside another struct

```
var.contents.programs[0].contents.datas.size = 10 ;  //e.g use according to your need
```